# Fastlane - Multiple codesigning identity

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, fastlane-match

We are facing a problem with fastlane. When checking certificate / profiles, the completion time is getting too (~50 minutes) :

`[2018-03-09 16:08:29.52]: Cloning remote git repo...
[2018-03-09 16:57:40.15]: Certificate 'XXXXXXX.cer' is already installed on this machine`

We are behind a proxy, but when accessing apple websites, we don't face any slowness issue.

Has anyone faced the same kind of issues ?

Many thanks for your help

EDIT : 
It turns out that when installing my certificates through match, the following commande `security find-identity -v -p codesigning`prints ~2000+ certificates ! I've tried to remove duplicates from my keychains, still facing the issue :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone comes accross my issue, this was caused by multiple duplicate lines within ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist

I guess this was caused by a wrong FL_UNLOCK_KEYCHAIN_PATH which was set to login.keychain instead of login.keychain-db